# Django allauth in admin instead of default user

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm using `Django 2` and have implemented user authentication using `django-allauth` plugin.

It is working fine from the frontend side, but the users are to be created by the superuser, therefore I need same integration in admin panel also.

As of now, Django-admin has default users model with `username` and `password` field but according to `django-allauth`, I'm using the only email and thus I want the user registration fields to be.

1. first_name
2. last_name
3. email
4. password

Could not understand how to implement `django-allauth` in the admin panel.

> Edit 2

Add user page in admin panel

[image]

How can I remove `username` field and add `email`, `first_name`, `last_name` fields?

Comment: Why not using the default django auth mechanism ?

Comment: because the default `Django auth` mechanism there is only two fields `username` and `password` while creating a user. In order to add `email`, I need to edit the user after adding a user. But in `allauth`, I'm using only `email` and `password` field hence need `first_name`, `last_name`, `email` and `password` field while adding a user.

Comment: Wrong, the default `User` auth mechanism has already, `username, first_name, last_name, email and password` fields. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/) for more details.

Comment: Please see `Edit 2` in the question. I meant to say that there is only `username` and `password` fields while adding a new user. How to add other fields?

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass the standard user creation and change forms, add your own fields and/or validation and then use those in a custom user admin. Assuming your user model is called User, an example below (Django 2.1.5, Python 3.6):

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput())

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model = User
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    add_fieldsets = UserAdmin.add_fieldsets + (
            (None, {'fields': ('email')}),
    )


admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

You can do similar customisation with the the `UserChangeForm`, but note that in the admin that needs to be overwritten with:

```
form = CustomUserChangeForm
fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets + ((None, {'fields': ()}),
    )
```

Comment: Where did you import "forms" from?